# Magento 2.1.4 while saving a bundle product with single drop-down product option duplicates the same option after saving the product

Tags: magento2

I was trying to create a bundle product in Magento-2.1.4 but while saving a bundle product with single drop-down product option duplicates the same option after saving the product.

Please see screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Please leave my edit alone, thanks - we tend to remove chatty material here. As it stands the question itself is rather light - would you show your readers what you have tried to solve your problem?

Comment: Unable to trace this issue....

Comment: If I used to delete these extra options they get double after saving the product :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of this conflict, in my case this was an issue because of an extension (Magento 2 SEO Extension), that I used for sitemap page generation.

I deleted the above module and removed the database modification done by it and bundle product started working properly again.

Hope it may help other who are facing the same problem due to this same scenario.

Thanks !!! Happy Coding :)